# How to exact match exact file extension .en.html with regular expression or other way in bash script

Tags: bash, regex

I am trying to match file name which ends with exactly .en.html using regex like .en.html$
For it works example z_.en.html but does not work with a.len.html - it matches with .len.html

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `.`, which is considered a wildcard in the regex:

```
~$ [[  z_.en.html =~ \.en\.html$ ]] && echo match || echo no_match
match
~$ [[  a.len.html =~ \.en\.html$ ]] && echo match || echo no_match
no_match
```

Also, https://regex101.com/ comes in very useful for debugging regex problems.